# Can't install UNetbootin in ubuntu 22.04 to flash a USB drive. What to do?

Tags: 22.04, unetbootin

I want update BIOS with FreeDOS. I want to use Ubuntu to make a live USB for FreeDOS. I tried using UNetbootin, but I can not install UNetbootin in Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

How can I make a live USB image image for FreeDOS in Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes?

Comment: I would suggest avoiding UNetbootin; Balena Etcher is more effective than Unetbootin in modern eras, and as you can see the PPA(s) you were adding to your system don't have release files and therefore doesn't support Jammy 22.04; Balena Etcher is the better solution.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it on topic

Comment: I need a detailed update method using the Balena Etcher program, I am a beginner and I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The PPA you added does not support Ubuntu 22.04. You can remove the PPA with

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
```

Since the latest version of Unetbootin downloaded from its webpage has issues in your computer (as you mentioned in comments), you can use another tool.

If you want to boot freedos, download the [LiveCD](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.3/official/FD13-LiveCD.zip), unzip it, and flash the IMG file to a USB drive using [Balena Etcher](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/download/v1.18.11/balena-etcher_1.18.11_amd64.deb).

Comment: ok , but i con not run unetbootin application can you help please.

Comment: i see this  libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile